# What is "instruction camouflage" obfuscation?

Tags: obfuscation

I have an obfuscated binary which only print a simple `Hello World!`
and exit like this:

```
Hello World!
```

But, when I am looking at the assembly with `objdump`, I cannot find any
call to `printf` or `write`, nor find the string `Hello World!`.

```
0804840c <main>:
 804840c:       be 1e 84 04 08          mov    $0x804841e,%esi
 8048411:       89 f7                   mov    %esi,%edi
 8048413:       b9 26 00 00 00          mov    $0x26,%ecx
 8048418:       ac                      lods   %ds:(%esi),%al
 8048419:       34 aa                   xor    $0xaa,%al
 804841b:       aa                      stos   %al,%es:(%edi)
 804841c:       e2 fa                   loop   8048418 <main+0xc>
 804841e:       23 4f 29                and    0x29(%edi),%ecx
 8048421:       46                      inc    %esi
 8048422:       ae                      scas   %es:(%edi),%al
 8048423:       29 4e 5a                sub    %ecx,0x5a(%esi)
 8048426:       29 6e ae                sub    %ebp,-0x52(%esi)
 8048429:       c2 9c 2e                ret    $0x2e9c
 804842c:       ae                      scas   %es:(%edi),%al
 804842d:       a2 42 17 54 55          mov    %al,0x55541742
 8048432:       55                      push   %ebp
 8048433:       23 46 69                and    0x69(%esi),%eax
 8048436:       e2 cf                   loop   8048407 <frame_dummy+0x27>
 8048438:       c6 c6 c5                mov    $0xc5,%dh
 804843b:       8a fd                   mov    %ch,%bh
 804843d:       c5 d8 c6 ce 8b          vshufps $0x8b,%xmm6,%xmm4,%xmm1
 8048442:       a0 aa 90 90 90          mov    0x909090aa,%al
 8048447:       90                      nop
 ...
 804844f:       90                      nop
```

The obfuscation technique claimed to be used here is called *instruction
camouflage* (see this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.125.5028)). Can someone explain what is it and how does it works ?

Comment: In general, a [mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) is a value applied on a bitfield via a bitwise operation, to read, set or reset a particular bit.

Comment: I agree the name must be changed. But, it seems to be extremely difficult to find a proper one. The point of this technique is mainly to conceal the executed code from a simple naive static analysis. For now, after discussions, "_code cloaking_" is the best I can come with... but I don't know if it would be accepted.

Comment: For me (personally), being understood by most of the community is more important than using a perfect - but new - word that no one has heard of and that might be misinterpreted (for that reason, I tend to use 'ROP' even if I personally prefer 'return-to-libc'). And 'hiding' and 'obfuscating' are way more widespread than 'cloaking' IMHO.

Comment: So, you would advise "_code hiding_" ? (code obfuscation cannot be an option because it cannot tag one technique among others). It is perfectly okay with me also. (Post-scriptum: 'ROP' and 'return-into-libc' are really two different techniques)

Comment: I found a reference about [instruction camouflage](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.125.5028). Though it is not a very well known paper, their name seems okay (I hope this is the last time I modify this... I'm just a mess, sorry).

Comment: As far as your terminology, I was thinking about it, and 'instruction camouflage' may not be ideal as other names (encryption wrapper to me) *because* both code and data are encrypted and 'instruction camouflage' implies that individual instructions might be morphed or regenerated so that their actual intent is obfuscated (e.g. poly/metamorphism). Oh, and camouflage is a real pain to spell!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instruction camouflage is an obfuscation technique against simple naive static
analysis of the binary. The binary program is composed of two parts:

- A decoder
- An encoded payload

When executed, the binary first goes to the decoder and decode the
payload that unveil the real assembly code. At the end, the decoder
jumps to the decoded payload and execute the code.

The benefit of this technique is that statically disassembling the
binary will not give you hints on what is really doing the program.
Somehow, it forces the analyst to execute first the decoder part (for
real or symbolically) and, then, look at the decoded payload.

In the proposed example, the decoder part is the following:

```
0804840c <main>:
 804840c:       be 1e 84 04 08          mov    $0x804841e,%esi
 8048411:       89 f7                   mov    %esi,%edi
 8048413:       b9 26 00 00 00          mov    $0x26,%ecx
 8048418:       ac                      lods   %ds:(%esi),%al
 8048419:       34 aa                   xor    $0xaa,%al
 804841b:       aa                      stos   %al,%es:(%edi)
 804841c:       e2 fa                   loop   8048418 <main+0xc>
```

You can see that there is a loop between `0x8048418` and `0x804841c`
which apply a xor `0xaa` to each byte in the payload (from `0x804841e`
to  `0x804841e + 0x25 = 0x8048443`, the loop counter is `%ecx`).

So, the best way to know what is done in the payload is to take `gdb`
and to set a breakpoint after the decoder has completed his task:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804840c
(gdb) run
Starting program: ./instruction_camouflage

Breakpoint 1, 0x0804840c in main ()
```

Lets check that the code hasn't change.

```
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function main:
=> 0x0804840c <+0>: mov    $0x804841e,%esi
   0x08048411 <+5>: mov    %esi,%edi
   0x08048413 <+7>: mov    $0x26,%ecx
   0x08048418 <+12>:    lods   %ds:(%esi),%al
   0x08048419 <+13>:    xor    $0xaa,%al
   0x0804841b <+15>:    stos   %al,%es:(%edi)
   0x0804841c <+16>:    loop   0x8048418 <main+12>
   0x0804841e <+18>:    and    0x29(%edi),%ecx
   0x08048421 <+21>:    inc    %esi
   0x08048422 <+22>:    scas   %es:(%edi),%al
   0x08048423 <+23>:    sub    %ecx,0x5a(%esi)
   0x08048426 <+26>:    sub    %ebp,-0x52(%esi)
   0x08048429 <+29>:    ret    $0x2e9c
   0x0804842c <+32>:    scas   %es:(%edi),%al
   0x0804842d <+33>:    mov    %al,0x55541742
   0x08048432 <+38>:    push   %ebp
   0x08048433 <+39>:    and    0x69(%esi),%eax
   0x08048436 <+42>:    loop   0x8048407 <frame_dummy+39>
   0x08048438 <+44>:    mov    $0xc5,%dh
   0x0804843b <+47>:    mov    %ch,%bh
   0x0804843d <+49>:    vshufps $0x8b,%xmm6,%xmm4,%xmm1
   0x08048442 <+54>:    mov    0x909090aa,%al
   0x08048447 <+59>:    nop
...
   0x0804844f <+67>:    nop
End of assembler dump.
```

Let's put a breakpoint just after the loop and continue till it is reached.

```
(gdb) break *0x0804841e
Breakpoint 2 at 0x804841e
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x0804841e in main ()
```

Now, we should be able to access the code as it will be executed.

```
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0804840c <+0>: mov    $0x804841e,%esi
   0x08048411 <+5>: mov    %esi,%edi
   0x08048413 <+7>: mov    $0x26,%ecx
   0x08048418 <+12>:    lods   %ds:(%esi),%al
   0x08048419 <+13>:    xor    $0xaa,%al
   0x0804841b <+15>:    stos   %al,%es:(%edi)
   0x0804841c <+16>:    loop   0x8048418 <main+12>
=> 0x0804841e <+18>:    and    %ebp,%esp
   0x08048420 <+20>:    sub    $0x4,%esp
   0x08048423 <+23>:    and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x08048426 <+26>:    add    $0x4,%esp
   0x08048429 <+29>:    push   $0x8048436
   0x0804842e <+34>:    call   0x80482f0 <puts@plt>
   0x08048433 <+39>:    mov    %ebp,%esp
   0x08048435 <+41>:    ret    
   0x08048436 <+42>:    dec    %eax
   0x08048437 <+43>:    gs
   0x08048438 <+44>:    insb   (%dx),%es:(%edi)
   0x08048439 <+45>:    insb   (%dx),%es:(%edi)
   0x0804843a <+46>:    outsl  %ds:(%esi),(%dx)
   0x0804843b <+47>:    and    %dl,0x6f(%edi)
   0x0804843e <+50>:    jb     0x80484ac <__libc_csu_init+76>
   0x08048440 <+52>:    and    %ecx,%fs:(%edx)
   0x08048443 <+55>:    add    %dl,-0x6f6f6f70(%eax)
   0x08048449 <+61>:    nop
   ...
   0x0804844f <+67>:    nop
End of assembler dump.
```

And, still there is these strange instructions after the `ret`, lets visualize it as a string.

```
(gdb) x /s 0x08048436
0x8048436 <main+42>:     "Hello World!\n"
```

So, we found all the pieces of the program and how it works.

Comment: Personally I've never heard the term "code masking" nor does Google or Wikipedia turn up any hints. Could you link to some resource where this term is actually used?

Comment: I don't know how to call this obfuscation. I couldn't find a proper generic name for this. Give some name, I'll change it in the question and in the answer.

Comment: I'm used to it being called naive encryption since I assume you mean the question to cover more than xor? E.g some simple combinations of rotations and xor? Otherwise it's a xor cipher. I actually can't think of a really good name for ciphers that are trivially reversible. Given your explanation the same sort of answer would cover any complex cipher scheme as well. I.e the operations between your entry point and breakpoint could be arbitrarily complex but would still fall to your technique. It doesn't rely on the cipher being trivial.

Comment: You exactly got my point. Strong encryption must be covered by the name of this obfuscation technique, but it must also allow to perform stupid "masking". So, "code encryption" was a bit too strong and too specific for what I was targeting. I thought that "masking" was a good compromised.

Comment: I think we just call this "self-modification".

Comment: Well, in my mind, self-modification comes from a meaningful code to another meaningful code... But, I might be wrong. And, even if you are right, then self-modification enclose a much wider spectrum of techniques than just masking the code in meaningless binary code.

Comment: "inlined self-decryption" ?

Comment: I don't see this is as an encryption/decryption algorithm because: 1) we give the algorithm and key in the code; 2) we decrypt it anyway before executing it. I strongly believe that "masking" (or a synonym) is the right term because it is all about temporarily hiding the code.

Comment: What about "code cloaking" ?

Comment: @PeterAndersson: possible this is a flawed translation from the OPs native language. Not everyone here is a native speaker of English. I for one am not.

Comment: Knowing the algorithm and key don't change the fact that it's a decryption. I wasn't suggesting a new word, I was mentioning the word I'd expect.

Comment: Nice write up on the classic encryption wrapper. Next up will need to be polymorphism, where the encryptor/decryptor is regenerated, so that no bytes in the file remain constant.

Comment: Isn't this just called a packer?

Answer (score 2):

This is also commonly known as an **encryption wrapper**. I'm sure there are several other similar names used in the industry.

The actual code isn't as important as the concept. The plaintext code is prepended (in executive order) by a decryption stub responsible for decoding the body of the code. In this way, the main code body (payload in the case of malware) is encrypted, and thus doesn't have constant bytes. The decoder stub itself remains constant in this example, though **polymorphism** is a later evolution that regenerates the encoder and decoder so that they, too, contain no constant bytes. By lessening the number of constant bytes between copies of the code, detection signature exposure is reduced.

Decoder stubs can offer decompression as well.

This mechanism got heavy use in the early days of self-replicating PC viruses. These were labeled with the characteristic of being **self-encrypting**. It is still used in today by some subversive software.

*Importantly, native code isn't the only code that can be 'wrapped' in this fashion.*