# How to produce binaries with "instruction camouflage" obfuscation?

Tags: tools, obfuscation

I would like to know what is the simplest way to produce code binaries with instruction camouflage (see [this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1673/what-is-a-instruction-camouflage-obfuscation)).

The problem here is that you first have to produce a correct assembly code and then to hide it with a given method directly into the binary. Doing it by hand is quite painful, especially if you have to take care of the static jumps into the code. Right now, I am using [nasm](http://www.nasm.us/), and more precisely its [preprocessor](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.10.07/html/nasmdoc4.html) to perform the camouflage operations. But, I wonder if there are better ways to do it.

So, what tools or tricks do you use to produce such binaries ?

Comment: This may be OT for reveng, since this site is mostly concerned with understanding such code.

Comment: @nneonneo good point.. is the creation of obfuscation and protection schemes on topic for a reverse engineering site. Or does the topic only cover understanding such schemes after they have been created? I think reverse engineers certainly have unique insights to these topics at least.

Comment: Yeah. It's most certainly a gray zone. I am of the opinion that the direct creation of obfuscation techniques, without a view to reversing them, is OT. In this early stage, it is really important to figure out what is and what isn't on topic.

Comment: I'm only using these to create crackme challenges for training my students to reverse-engineering. Marking it as OT is a bit harsh because we have to study both side of domain to pretend understand a bit what is going on, in my humble opinion.

Comment: @perror Well, even started as question for good reasons, it definitely can be used for malicious purposes too. Especially in creating *"cryptors"* - programs, which purpose is to obfuscate binary payload to prevent RE analysis and signature-based detection. There are few of them available as sources on grey-zone resources.

Comment: @DenisLaskov: this kinda touches the [dual-use tool topic](http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/111) on meta.RE.SE. Kitchen knives can also be used to chop spices or to kill your wife. Luckily politicians haven't been able to cause a mass hysteria out of that fact and subsequently outlawed knives ;)

Comment: @0xc0000022l :) well, there are plenty of tools to kill Your wife in this case. Ticket You posted -  about tools, that violate license agreement or patents. Here we talking about sharing methodology to make work of good guys harder, and bad guys easier. For me this is major criteria of "bad topics". There are reasons, why "dirty bomb recipe" not into chemistry textbook for pupils or even students, even if it just chemistry formulas. IMHO.

Comment: @DenisLaskov: oops, my bad. Meant to [link this one](http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/52)

Comment: This question **is** on-topic. If you disagree, reason about it [here](http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/21/60).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general what you do is that you make a new segment in the executable, change the entry point to your new segment. Your new segment has the decryption code for the original code and the changed entry point now means that the first code to execute when the executable is loaded is your decryption code.

Your encryption code then either maps a segment, usually at the address where the original executable segment was located, and decrypts the source segment into the mapped segment or it directly decrypts the segment in place. If your code decrypts the segment in place you need to make sure the remove any relocations from the original executable.

In all cases, except if you get to map your decrypted executable segment at its original intended address, you need to do the relocations yourself after decryption so that the executable won't crash. Personally I would implement the relocations in order to support things like ASLR. After decryption and relocation you simply call into the original entry point.

This way you do not have to create your encryption or "masking" code for a particular binary and applying it to arbitrary binaries in the future should be possible.